# css, javascript -- where to start?

Tags: javascript, css

I am a C/C++ programmer with more than 10 years of experience. I also know python and perl, but I've never used this languages for a web development.

Now for some reasons I want to move into the web development realm and as part of that transition I have to learn css, javascript, (x)html etc.

So I need an advice for a good sources of information for such topics. For a while I don't want to read lengthy tutorials, I want something quick and dirty, something to start with.

Answer (score 6):

You can learn style and best practices on [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/) web site.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are an experienced programmer, a good place to start with javascript might be [Javascript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) by Douglas Crockford. It is a brief but thorough tour of, well, the best parts of javascript (and pretty much all you'll need for quite a while).

Your approach to CSS and HTML will have to be very different. I suggest trying to make a static site or two, checking reference material if you get stuck. Pick a site that you like, and try recreating the basic layout in HTML. Got the layout? Try making it look pretty. Repeat.

Comment: I read this book, but did not like it, and would not recommend it. It is more like a catalog without explanations on why he describes is good.

Comment: True, he does often use the idiom "as I'm sure you can see this makes foo in javascript very expressive" without going into much more detail, but he DOES explain (in the appendices) why the parts of the language he excludes should be avoided. Guess it's not for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend you look at [Dev Opera](http://dev.opera.com/), its full of up to date information with a strong focus on webstandards. In particular, the [Web Standards Curriculum](http://dev.opera.com/articles/wsc/) is a great resource for beginners to get started.

I really wouldn't rely on the W3 Schools site, its content isn't kept as up to date and the examples often show bad-practice. If you know what you're doing it can be good as a quick resource for a single technique, but for a beginner it could easily lead you down the wrong path.

Answer (score 2):

I found http://htmldog.com/ to be useful when learning HTML/CSS. It teaches w3c compliant HTML and CSS, unlike many other sites. Looking at other people's CSS is also really useful. CSS is pretty simple (ignoring all the browser incompatibilites), so even will little CSS knowledge you can figure out what other people are doing.

Javascript is more complicated. Javascript has a pretty strange object system (it uses prototypal inheritance), so it's best to pick up a book. Crockford's Javascript: The Good Parts is an excellenent book to learn the fundamentals of javascript. The thing about javascript is that are basically two parts to it: the language, and the DOM (document object model). Most of the time, javascript is used in the browser, which means it has to interact with HTML via the DOM. Many people don't realize that javascript can be used outside of a web browser. JS: The Good Parts will teach you the javascript core, then you can look up the DOM interaction elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I won't suggest w3schools for CSS and XHTML, but [htmldog.com](http://www.htmldog.com). I would suggest something about unobtrouse JavaScript for JS.

Answer (score 0):

My favourite CSS tutorial site has always been [www.htmldog.com](http://www.htmldog.com). The reason I like it so much is that not only does it teach you CSS, it also teaches you to drop any bad html habits you may have picked up over the years. In my view learning to write clean, semantic html is an important precursor to really getting to grips with css.

As for javascript, w3schools is probably best

Comment: Aaargh - can't believe I said that! What an idiot I was.

Comment: Live and learn.  :)  I didn't realize that anything was wrong with w3schools, either, until I found a link to w3fools.com off of SO.

Answer (score 0):

For CSS, how about CSS in a Nutshell, by O'Reilly?  Nice and thin.

Answer (score 0):

Opera recently put a lot of effort into getting people to write a [bunch of tutorials](http://opera.com/wsc/). The quality is high, and they pay attention to feedback (unlike W3Schools). It covers HTML, CSS and JavaScript and I haven't come across a better starting point.

Answer (score -1):

[W 3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) is a neat beginner/novice reference and tutorial site.

The site covers most technologies used in web-development.

Comment: Heh! Guess people beat me to it :)

Comment: Hehe there were 7 sec between us :P

Comment: It's worth noting that W3Schools is real quick and dirty.  You will crave practice when you are done, because you know you haven't mastered anything yet.

Comment: I wouldn't just class W3 Schools as beginner/novice - I and all my colleagues, find myself double checking code snippets and syntax from there. It's a great resource.

Comment: I'd class W3Schools as error prone and rubbish. Happily better alternatives exist today.

Answer (score -1):

Install [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

- It helps inspecting html.
- You can edit CSS on the fly.
- Has a JavaScript console.

[Here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/10-reasons-why-you-should-be-using-firebug/) is a nice article explaining the some features of [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: How would this help a novice?  A novice who doesn't know what firebug is!

Comment: edited answers with main firebug features

Comment: Firebug is a useful tool, but the starting point should be documentation, not debuggers.

Comment: I disagree. Firebug's not just a debugger - it's a good playground, and for many people (including myself in my early programming days) documentation can be quite opaque and abstract. Having said that, a better playground (for CSS at least) might be http://cssdesk.com/

Answer (score -3):

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) is a good place to start.

However, you might also benefit by poking around the [Mozilla Developer Centre](https://developer.mozilla.org/En) (MDC), which has lots of information about HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. I now almost exclusively use the MDC for looking things up—it has lots of examples, lots of detail (if you want to go into it), and it shows you many different things that you can do with the item you're looking up.

Also, for JavaScript, after you've learnt the basics ("[A re-introduction to JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript)" on the MDC is a good place to start), Douglas Crockford's [JavaScript page](http://javascript.crockford.com/) and John Resig's "[Learning Advanced JavaScript](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/)" make for excellent reading.

Steve

Comment: W3Schools has lots of examples of worst practise, and lots of misinformation. It isn't a good place to start. It was just the best resource available half a decade ago.

Answer (score -5):

The W3Schools site has a try it yourself section that i think will be perfect for you.

[W3Schools CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/default.asp)

[W3Schools Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/default.asp)